# querystring values truncated while sending it through xmlHttpRequest in Javascript to another php page?

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am passing this url value in demoUrlName (text field id) in my form
For Example ,  http://common360.info/browse.php?u=uushJYHAjQLTHh2twPpHjQMbEl4%3D&b=5&f=norefer

And I used xmlHttpRequest to redirect this value to one another page.
The problem is, while sending the form values through xmlHttpRequest and in the redirected page  , url value is truncated as
http://common360.info/browse.php?u=uushJYHAjQLTHh2twPpHjQMbEl4=

How to send the values as it is I was entered in form.

my code is ,

```
    var str = trim(document.getElementById('demoUrlName').value);
    var str = "action=demo&url="+str+"&urlqstr="+urlqstr+"&pgesrc="+pgesrc+"&r="+ran_number;
    var url = "demo/demoTool.php";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);  
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send(str);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used escape() function it send the values as it is in form

Answer (score 2):

Use [the `encodeURIComponent` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode `&` as data instead of using them as "key/value pair seperator character"

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to encode the values.

[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)